# How to clear Apex Oracle debug history from SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Oracle Apex 19.2 workspace and I would like to clear the debug history from SQL Developer.

I have tried :

```
apex_debug.REMOVE_DEBUG_BY_APP(p_application_id =>1401);
-- Or
delete from apex_debug_messages
```

but none of them works.

What I'm doing actually is creating a page that is not used in my apps and add the code

```
apex_debug.REMOVE_DEBUG_BY_APP(p_application_id =>1401);
```

This code works only from a page context.

Is possible to remove the history from SQL Developer please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are connected as a user that has the role `APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE` granted to the user, you can run the code below to remove the debug messages.

```
BEGIN
    APEX_UTIL.set_workspace ('WORKSPACE_NAME');
    APEX_DEBUG.REMOVE_DEBUG_BY_APP (p_application_id => 1401);
END;
```